# Error in sending Arraylist to Adapter in Recycler view in Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an `arraylist` `CastArrayList` in which data is added in the `onResponse` method of `Volley` and from there I want to check if the size of `CastArrayList` is greater than 7, another arraylist `subCastArrayList` copies the `CastArraylist` from position 0 to 7 and send it to `RecyclerView` but not getting any view in `RecyclerView`. I want if `CastArrayList` size is greater than 7 `SubCastArrayList` should copy first 7 elements else copy the whole `CastArrayList` and then send the `SubCastArrayList` to `adapter`.

```
ArrayList<Cast> castArrayList;
ArrayList<Cast> subCastArrayList;
castArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
subCastArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

castDetailAdapter = new 
CastDetailAdapter(MovieView.this,castArrayList,subCastArrayList);

RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

recycler_view.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recycler_view.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recycler_view.setAdapter(castDetailAdapter);

StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            int i;
            for (i=0;i<movieDetailFull.getCredits().getCast().size();i++) {
                Cast cast = new Cast();

                cast.setName(movieDetailFull.getCredits().getCast().get(i).getName());

                cast.setId(movieDetailFull.getCredits().getCast().get(i).getId());

                castArrayList.add(i,cast);
                castDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        if (castArrayList.size() > 7) {

            subCastArrayList  = new ArrayList<Cast>
            (castArrayList.subList(0,6));
            castDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else {
            subCastArrayList = new ArrayList<Cast>(castArrayList);
            castDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the reference of `subCastArrayList` list by creating new arraylist mean now `subCastArrayList` and list in adapter are two different reference to different list

so just add elements to it

```
subCastArrayList.clear();
// ^^^ clear the list instead of creating new one inside if or else
if (castArrayList.size() > 7)
{
    //subCastArrayList.addAll(castArrayList.subList(0,6));
    subCastArrayList.addAll(castArrayList.subList(0,7));
    // upper range is exclusive so use              ^ 
}else{
    subCastArrayList.addAll(castArrayList);
}
    castDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   // move notify outside , avoid redundant statements
```

Comment: i am glad that i could help, happy coding